# How to compare items between two JArray objects and call a method only when they are different

Tags: c#, json

I am comparing two Newtonsoft JArrays. I am looping through the first one and then using Linq to find whether the second JArray has an object with the same id and sortOrder values. Only if they are different, then the UpdateData method should be executed. I have enclosed the code and the two JArray data below. Based on the data, since the first item has both id and sortOrder the same between the two JArrays, it should not call the UpdateData method and the foundItem should be a valid object. But it comes as null instead and the UpdateData() method is called. The UpdateData() method should be called only for the second and third items as they have different sortOrder.

```
private void CheckSaveDataLogic(JArray featuredProductsData, JArray originalFeaturedProductsData)
    {

        foreach (JObject item in featuredProductsData)
        { 
            if(originalFeaturedProductsData != null)
            {
                var foundItem = originalFeaturedProductsData
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<int>("Id") == 
      Convert.ToInt32(item.GetValue("id")) && x.Value<int>("sortOrder") == 
      Convert.ToInt32(item.GetValue("sortOrder")));
                if(foundItem == null)
                {
                    UpdateData(item, isFeatured);
                }
            }                                            
        }
    }

featuredProductsData JArray:
{[
  {
    "id": "2190",
    "sortOrder": 1
  },      
  {
    "id": "2436",
    "sortOrder": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "1874",
    "sortOrder": 3
  }
]}

originalFeaturedProductsData JArray:

{[
  {
    "id": "2190",
    "sortOrder": 1
  },      
  {
    "id": "1874",
    "sortOrder": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "2436",
    "sortOrder": 3
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is case-sensitive.

`Id` is not `id`; your JSON indicates the key is `id` yet your code is checking for `Id`

Try this:

```cs
var foundItem = originalFeaturedProductsData
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<int>("id") == 
      Convert.ToInt32(item.GetValue("id")) && x.Value<int>("sortOrder") == 
      Convert.ToInt32(item.GetValue("sortOrder")));
```